# Extract keys and data and write an array

Tags: json, jq

Given the following json source

```
{
  "pages":{
        "yomama/first key": {
            "data": {
                "fieldset": "lesson-video-overview",
                "title": "5th Grade Math - Interpreting Fractions",
            },
            "order": 4
        },

        "yomama/second key": {
            "data": {
                "fieldset": "lesson-video-clip-single",
                "title": "Post-Lesson Debrief Part 5",
            },
            "order": 14
        },
        "yopapa/Third key": {
            "data": {
                "fieldset": "lesson-video-clip-single",
                "title": "Lesson Part 2B",
            },
            "order": 6
        }
    }
}
```

How could I output an array-type output like this? The main challenge for me is extracting the key e.g. "yomama/first key" and in the ideal world, I can filter like just give me an array of those keys that start with "yomama" (but not yopapa)

```
[

    {
        "url" : "yomama/first key",
        "data": {
            "fieldset": "lesson-video-overview",
            "title": "5th Grade Math - Interpreting Fractions",
        },
        "order": 4
    },
    {
        "url" : "yomama/second key",
        "data": {
            "fieldset": "lesson-video-clip-single",
            "title": "Post-Lesson Debrief Part 5",
        },
        "order": 14
    },
    {
        "url" : "yopapa/Third key",
        "data": {
            "fieldset": "lesson-video-clip-single",
            "title": "Lesson Part 2B",
        },
        "order": 6
    }

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input is in `so.json` and corrected to well-formatted JSON you may use:

```
jq '[.pages | to_entries[] | {"url": .key, "data": .value.data, "order": .value.order}]' < so.json
```

Comment: That is awesome thanks.  Only part missing - can we select those url's that start with  "yomama/" ?  I think I can probably figure that out from the output later on if it isn't trivial

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does not require being explicit about including all the other keys:

```
.pages
| [ to_entries[]
    | select(.key | startswith("yomama"))
    | {url: .key} + .value ]
```

Comment: Thanks @peak, that is very kind of you to add your improved version.  I'm sure that will help others trying to solve similar problems